# Changing data frame structure in R

Tags: r, dataframe, gis

In R:
I need to change the format of a df. The data frame currently looks like:

```
   long         lat         cld       tmin        tmax       presence
-78.68224   -0.029785    1.927959   0.1321229   0.5416985       1   
-75.89100   -5.373100   -0.4832732  0.1596707   0.5800908       1
```

But I need it to look like this, with all the variables assigned to their correct value:

```
lat            lon     presence  variable   value
0.029785    -78.68224     1       cld      1.927959
5.373100    -75.89100     1       cld     -0.4832732
0.029785    -78.68224     1       tmin     0.1321229
5.373100    -75.89100     1       tmin     0.1596707
  ...         ....       ...      ....        ...
0.029785    -78.68224     1       tmax.    0.5416985
```

This is the example line provided but I can't figure out how to apply it to my df because I do not have a "data" column or object to call for the values.

```
df.gg <- reshape::melt(df.gg@data,id.vars=c("lat","lon","presence"),variable.name="variable")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you need? You can pivot all the cols except the ones you can choose to exclude like:

```
> tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, -c(long, lat, presence), names_to="variable")
# A tibble: 6 x 5
   long     lat presence variable   value
  <dbl>   <dbl>    <int> <chr>  <dbl>
1 -78.7 -0.0298        1 cld    1.93 
2 -78.7 -0.0298        1 tmin   0.132
3 -78.7 -0.0298        1 tmax   0.542
4 -75.9 -5.37          1 cld   -0.483
5 -75.9 -5.37          1 tmin   0.160
6 -75.9 -5.37          1 tmax   0.580
```

Comment: unfortunately, I get an error that states I do not have that %>% function. Is there another way?

Comment: I'm installing tidyr now. is there a good way to verify that variables are matching the appropriate values?

Answer (score 2):

`data.table`

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(setDT(df.gg), id.vars= c("lat","long","presence"), variable.name="variable")
```

see comments from r2Evans:

`reshape2::melt(dat, c("lat", "long", "presence"))`

Output:

```
         lat      long presence variable      value
1: -0.029785 -78.68224        1      cld  1.9279590
2: -5.373100 -75.89100        1      cld -0.4832732
3: -0.029785 -78.68224        1     tmin  0.1321229
4: -5.373100 -75.89100        1     tmin  0.1596707
5: -0.029785 -78.68224        1     tmax  0.5416985
6: -5.373100 -75.89100        1     tmax  0.5800908
```

data:

```
df.gg <- structure(list(long = c(-78.68224, -75.891), lat = c(-0.029785, 
-5.3731), cld = c(1.927959, -0.4832732), tmin = c(0.1321229, 
0.1596707), tmax = c(0.5416985, 0.5800908), presence = c(1, 1
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: As an option, this work just as well *without* `data.table`: `reshape2::melt(dat, c("lat", "long", "presence"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can get some samples from [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/)

```
library(tidyr)
data_long <- gather(df.gg, condition, measurement, cld:tmax, factor_key=TRUE)
data_long
```

Answer

```
    # A tibble: 6 x 5
   long     lat presence condition measurement
  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>
1 -78.7 -0.0298        1 cld             1.93 
2 -75.9 -5.37          1 cld            -0.483
3 -78.7 -0.0298        1 tmin            0.132
4 -75.9 -5.37          1 tmin            0.160
5 -78.7 -0.0298        1 tmax            0.542
6 -75.9 -5.37          1 tmax            0.580
```